# Pandas Freeze column names

Tags: python, excel, pandas, python-2.7, pycharm

I want to freeze the column names and like from large files when I'm scrolling down to have always the name of the columns.

This is my script where I'm also creating the excel file with multiple excels as sheets.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from timestampdirectory import  createdir
import openpyxl
import xlsxwriter
from openpyxl import workbook
from openpyxl import worksheet

import os
import time
def svnanalysis():

    dest = createdir()
    dfSvnUsers = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(dest, "SvnUsers.xlsx"))
    dfSvnUsers.fillna("N/A", inplace=True)
    dfSvnGroupMembership = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(dest, "SvnGroupMembership.xlsx"))
    dfSvnRepoGroupAccess = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(dest, "SvnRepoGroupAccess.xlsx"))
    dfsvnReposSize = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(dest, "svnReposSize.xlsx"))
    dfsvnRepoLastChangeDate = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(dest, "svnRepoLastChangeDate.xlsx"))
    dfUserDetails = pd.read_excel(r"D:\GIT-files\Automate-Stats\SVN_sample_files\CM_UsersDetails.xlsx")
    dfUserDetails.fillna("N/A", inplace=True)

    timestr = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-")
    xlwriter = pd.ExcelWriter(os.path.join(dest,f'{timestr}Usage-SvnAnalysis.xlsx'))

    dfUserDetails.to_excel(xlwriter, sheet_name='UserDetails',index = False)
    dfSvnUsers.to_excel(xlwriter, sheet_name='SvnUsers', index = False )
    dfSvnGroupMembership.to_excel(xlwriter, sheet_name='SvnGroupMembership', index = False )
    dfSvnRepoGroupAccess.to_excel(xlwriter, sheet_name='SvnRepoGroupAccess', index = False)
    dfsvnReposSize.to_excel(xlwriter, sheet_name='svnReposSize', index = False)
    dfsvnRepoLastChangeDate.to_excel(xlwriter, sheet_name='svnRepoLastChangeDate',index= False)

    for column in dfSvnUsers:
        column_width = max(dfSvnUsers[column].astype(str).map(len).max(), len(column))
        col_idx = dfSvnUsers.columns.get_loc(column)
        xlwriter.sheets['SvnUsers'].set_column(col_idx, col_idx, column_width)
        xlwriter.sheets['UserDetails'].set_column(col_idx, col_idx, column_width)
        xlwriter.sheets['SvnGroupMembership'].set_column(col_idx, col_idx, column_width)
        xlwriter.sheets['SvnRepoGroupAccess'].set_column(col_idx, col_idx, column_width)
        xlwriter.sheets['svnReposSize'].set_column(col_idx, col_idx, column_width)
        xlwriter.sheets['svnRepoLastChangeDate'].set_column(col_idx, col_idx, column_width)

    # xlwriter.freeze_columns(1, 0)  # # Freeze the first row.

    xlwriter.close()

    #usage = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(dest,f'{timestr}Usage-SvnAnalysis.xlsx'))
    #usage.style.set_table_styles([
     #   {'selector': 'thead th', 'props': 'position: sticky; top:0; background-color:red;'},
      #  {'selector': 'tbody th', 'props': 'position: sticky; left:0; background-color:green;'}
    #]).to_html()

    print("UsageSvnAnalysis.xlsx a fost exportat cu succes continand ca sheet toate xlsx anterioare")
svnanalysis()
```

At the end of the script with the "#"(commented lines) its what I tried, on the part with table_styles... all works but its not freezing or changing the color for first row of each color (name of column)

This is the exported Excel:

and basically now when I'm scrolling down the column names should always appears and have "blue" background but as I say n the # line of code all works but its not applying idk why

```
    for dfSvnUsers in xlwriter.sheets:
        ws = xlwriter.sheets['SvnUsers']
        ws.freeze_panes(1, 0)

        ws.style.set_table_styles([
        {'selector': 'thead th', 'props': 'position: sticky; top:0; background-color:red;'},
        {'selector': 'tbody th', 'props': 'position: sticky; left:0; background-color:green;'}
        ]).to_html()
```

I updated the script, now work and freeze the first row with column names for the specific sheet, but I tried to change also the color of that background in "red" and didn't work,

[image: colorchange]

Comment: Notice that you're making these cosmetic changes *after* you have already written out the `xlsx` files and closed out the file descriptor...

Comment: This topic/answer will probably help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25476081/why-cant-i-freeze-panes-on-the-xlsxwriter-object-pandas-is-creating-for-me

Comment: hi, ty for help, i know, i tried also and inside the xlwritter but same ...

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter(Your_FilePath, engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
    dfUserDetails.to_excel(xlwriter, sheet_name='UserDetails',index = False)

    # etc etc ...

    for sht_name in writer.sheets:
            ws = writer.sheets[sht_name]
            ws.freeze_panes(1, 0)

    print("UsageSvnAnalysis.xlsx a fost exportat cu succes continand ca sheet toate xlsx anterioare")
svnanalysis()
```

Comment: [updatedscirpt](https://imgur.com/a/sYbT21t)   ty, its worked but now i tried t ochange and the background collor for that row in blue, but idk why dont work

Comment: please update your question with the specific requirements you need, I will look into it tomorrow and will update my answer accordingly.