# Applying styles to the headers of pandas-generated excel files

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, xlsxwriter

Reviewing [Tim Hoffman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2726279/tim-hoffmann)'s  answer to [this broader question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24065547/apply-styles-while-exporting-to-xlsx-in-pandas-with-xlsxwriter) made me want to make my headers wrap.

I tried this with the following code:

```
import pandas.core.format
pandas.core.format.header_style["alignment"].update({"text_wrap" : True})
pandas.core.format.header_style["font"].update({"bold" : False})
```

Now, the actual result is NOT bolded, so I know I'm managing to overwrite the default. However, the text is not wrapping.

Based on what I see in the [xlsxwriter format class guide](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/format.html#set_text_wrap) and that there's already an *alignment* keyword...

```
ipdb> pandas.core.format.header_style["alignment"]
{'horizontal': 'center', 'vertical': 'top'}
```

...and that after I modify it as per above...

```
ipdb> pandas.core.format.header_style["alignment"].update({"text_wrap" : True})
ipdb> pandas.core.format.header_style["alignment"]
{'horizontal': 'center', 'text_wrap': True, 'vertical': 'top'}
```

...I would expect to get the result, but I'm not. Anyone know why?

I gather that I could also re-write the data using an xlsxwriter write method, but that feels like more work to me, so I'm hoping to make it work *this* way.

Answer (score 0):

> I would expect to get the result, but I'm not. Anyone know why?

AFAIK the `header_style` dict that you are modifying is internal and isn't exposed via an API.

The `header_style` dict is in the `xlwt` `easyxf` format which is only partially mapped by the `xlsxwriter` engine in Pandas to get the default heading formats. The `text_wrap` property [isn't one that is mapped](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/io/excel.py#L1479) (and because the format is internal I don't think it needs to be).

So overall I don't think you can rely on this workaround.