# Applying table style to excel using python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

I'm trying to apply a style to an excel table using python.
I've read this:
[Apply styles while exporting to 'xlsx' in pandas with XlsxWriter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24065547/apply-styles-while-exporting-to-xlsx-in-pandas-with-xlsxwriter)
It is not passible to apply a style during the export of a  dataframe to  excel.
I'm trying to open a saved excel file and set the style using openpyxl and tableStyleInfo, but without success.

How can I change a table style?

Comment: Does this help? https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html

Comment: Welcome to SO! It is often useful to provide a [minimally reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your issue

Comment: What have you tried so far?