# how to format specific cells in excel using xlsx package in python

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

I have a pandas df which I am formatting using xlsx package currently I have the option to format an entire row or column using xlsx but not specific cells also I would like to insert few lines in between the DF.

Image attached how I want the excel file to look.

The below code gives me the file in the 1st part of the image. I need to do some more formatting like inserting new lines and making D13 and E13 in italics. [image]

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Sample Report Test.xlsx' , engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer , index= False , sheet_name='Sample Report')

workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sample Report']

money_fmt = workbook.add_format({'num_format':'$#,##0' ,  'font_name':'Batang' })
font_fmt = workbook.add_format({'font_name':'Batang' , 'bold':True })
tot_fmt = workbook.add_format({'num_format':'$#,##0' ,  'font_name':'Batang' ,  'bold':True })

worksheet.set_column('A:B' , 25 , font_fmt)
worksheet.set_column('C:P' , 15 , money_fmt)
worksheet.set_row(4, None , tot_fmt)
worksheet.set_row(7 , None , tot_fmt)

writer.save()
```

Answer (score 4):

You can insert more than one dataframe, with offsets, into an XlsxWriter file. See [this example](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html#handling-multiple-pandas-dataframes) from the docs.

It isn't possible to format cells after they are written (apart from column/row formats, see [this example](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html#formatting-of-the-dataframe-output)).

If you need very fine grained formatting you would be best to just use XlsxWriter directly with the data from the dataframe.

Some people use conditional formatting in XlsxWriter to get the effect they need, like this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352907/apply-format-to-a-cell-after-being-written-in-xlsxwriter/35865454#35865454).

Comment: You can also use conditional formatting to single-cell ranges, e.g. "A1:A1"

Comment: Yes I know (I wrote XlsxWriter ) so I’m not sure why I wrote that they aren’t applicable to single cells. I’ll remove that comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
money_italic_fmt = workbook.add_format({'num_format':'$#,##0',
                                        'font_name':'Batang',
                                        'italic':True})
worksheet.write(12, # <-- The cell row (zero indexed).
                3,  # <-- The cell column (zero indexed).
                13, # <-- Value to write
                money_italic_fmt  # <-- Format
)
```

Comment: What if I just need to format without writing as there is already data in that cell what modification I need to do ?

Comment: @yasinmohammed, i'm not sure that you can do this... You mat try to write the same value

Comment: Since My original file may have multiple values which get calculated and nos will change weekly writing down the nos in the code every week does not sound feasible

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional formatting. E.g. this code paints A1 cell in nice colors

```
header_format = workbook.add_format({'bold':     True,
                                     'font_color': '#FDCC02',
                                     'bg_color': '#003318'})
worksheet.conditional_format('A1:A1', {'type':   'no_errors',
                                       'format': header_forma})
```