# How to format the Excel Report through ExcelWriter

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsxwriter

I am trying to make certain cell( not the entire column) in my Excel Report bold, italic.

I was able to make the entire column bold( or italic). However, I want to make a specific cell bold or italic.

```
format = workbook.add_format(bold_format)
worksheet.set_column(1,10, bold_format)
```

Any idea how to do this ?

Comment: You might want to read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41588983/5741205) from XlsxWriter's author