# Python - Export $ numbers to excel as numbers, not string

Tags: python, dataframe, formatting, export-to-excel

I have a dataframe and I need to format one column to $xxx.xx. When I export to excel I need the numbers in float format but they are strings. How to export them as float?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=['index1', 'index2', 'index3'], 
          columns=["A", "B", "C"], 
          data=[[5,34, "ok"], [7,8,"fine"], ["3rd",100,np.nan]])
df['B'] = (df['B']).apply(lambda x: '${:,.2f}'.format(x))
df
```

[image]

The exported excel has B column in string format:

[image]

What I need:

[image]

Comment: Haha Psidom you got me again. I changed my name from AlexMeow to this. In excel you can easily select the numbers and go to the toolbar then select the "$". But they stay as number.

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41567847/how-to-format-specific-cells-in-excel-using-xlsx-package-in-python) what you want?

Comment: I do not want to do any manual work during the process so exporting to excel then add $ is not in consideration for now, unless there's no better solution.

Comment: Note: I am not a dataframe user. However, If I need more advanced Excel outputs, I use `xlsxwriter`.