# How to expand Excel cells with new line?

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I write a testing Python program, as follow:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet("a")
worksheet.write(0,0, "b\r\nc\r\nd")
workbook.close()
```

It is expected there will be a cell filled with 3 lines. But when I open it, the three letters are in one line, until I double click the cell like this:

[image]

When I download a sheet from doc.google.com, the multiline cells will shrink into one line. After double-click, it will expands.

So, is there any way I can batch expand the cells rather than double click on each one?

Comment: probably `set_text_wrap()`, and usually only `\n` is used for new line character in excel cells

Comment: @Slai Thanks a lot for your response. IT DOES WORK. But I may want find a trick in Excel so that I can use it also after downloading files from Google doc. It's why I only add an excel flag. I'll accept this if I found no Excel tricks in several days.

Comment: seems like there is no way to apply formatting to existing file https://stackoverflow.com/a/22353696/1383168, so you might need different module for that

Comment: Before you double click, does the cell have Word Wrap on? Perhaps it's off, but by double clicking, it turns it on...therefore you could just apply word-wrapping to all the necessary cells?

Comment: @BruceWayne Yes. Thanks. You have helped me get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following steps work:

1. Select all
2. Click the Wrap Text Button(Home - Alignment - Wrap Text [image])
3. Adapt the width of columns and height of rows if necessary.

[image]

Thanks to @BruceWayne's question in comment.

Thanks for @Slai's Answer. In a Python script, `set_text_wrap()` can be used to make same influnce with the action above. The full code:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet("a")
cell_format = workbook.add_format()
cell_format.set_text_wrap()
worksheet.write(0,0, "b\nc\nd", cell_format)
workbook.close()
```